# find users with consecutive logins sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have table contains 2 columns; customer_id, login_date.
For each day, if a customer has logged in, there will be 1 entry in the table for that customer.

```
Customer_id login_date
--------------------
1   31-Dec-2018
2   31-Dec-2018
3   31-Dec-2018
1   1-Jan-2019
2   1-Jan-2019
3   2-Jan-2019
2   2-Jan-2019
3   3-Jan-2019
3   4-Jan-2019
```

I need to get the ids of customers who have logged in for at least 3 consecutive days.
Expected output is like below.

```
Customer_id
------
2
3
```

So far i have achieved this using below query .

```
select customer_id from (
select *, case when (lag(logindate,1) over (partition by customer_id order by logindate)) = dateadd(day, -1,logindate) then 1 else 0 end second_day ,
            case when (lag(logindate,2) over (partition by customer_id order by logindate)) = dateadd(day, -2,logindate) then 1 else 0 end third_day
from login_history
) a 
where a.second_day =1 and a.third_day =1;
```

But if i have to get customers with 5 consecutive logins i have to keep on adding lag columns.
Is there any better way to get this done?

Comment: Don't tag 3 completely different RDBMS and an IDE for none of those RDBMS. Only tag the RDBMS you are actually using. I have removed all these conflicting tags. Please retag the RDBMS you are using and **only** the RDBMS you are using./

Comment: Could a user log in multiple times on the same day?

Comment: No there will be single entry per user per day

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `lag()` or `lead()`:

```
select distinct customer_id
from (select t.*,
             lag(login_date, 2) over (partition by customer_id order by login_date) as prev2_login_date
      from t
     ) t
where prev2_login_date = dateadd(day, -2, login_date);
```

This looks at the login date two rows behind.  If it is two days before the current day -- then voila! Three days in a row.  This uses the fact that you do not have duplicate dates for a given customer.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=21d43270755ad597700496f4b3b44f6f) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Can you please explain this query a little bit more.  i am not getting expected result using this query

Comment: @MaheshKalani . . . The answer had a typo -- the second argument to the `lag()` was `1` rather than `2`.  I fixed the problem and added a db<>fiddle.